# Disable php execution directly with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this on my htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

And in the index.php I get the REQUEST_URI so I can know what page to display.

But I have another files .php, how to make that all php execution like http://domain.com/file.php directs to index.php?

If I the line "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f" then the sitemap.xml is not working.

Sorry for my bad english, and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have it like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # route all *.php to /index.php
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[/\s?] [NC]
    RewriteRule !^index\.php$ index.php [L,NC]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```